# Copy and paste a non-spatial record in the same table (make a duplicate a record)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, table

How can I duplicate (copy/paste) a non-spatial record into the same table in ArcMap? I can copy and paste to/from spatial tables, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the attribute table of a non-spatial table (there's no paste button).

I need a way to copy and paste, as a common editing task (multiple times per minute). Maybe with one or two clicks, and no noticeable processing time. I would have thought I'd be able to copy and paste, just as I do with many other computer programs.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Comment: Here is a link explaining how to join and relate tables within ArcGIS. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-and-relating-tables.htm.

Comment: How does this help me copy and paste non-spatial records?

Comment: Oh- I assumed the spatial data and the table were related. If not, why don't you just use Access or Excel on the table?   If so, joining your non-spatial data to your spatial data will result in new columns in your spatial data with the values from the non-spatial data. Then you can use the field calculator to populate columns.

Comment: Highlight the row you want to copy, Control C. Click on empty row, control V.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do this. Does this work for you in a non-spatial table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of ArcGIS Pro 3.1, it's possible to duplicate a record in a standalone table using the ***duplicate*** context-menu option in the attribute table.

[image]

Implemented Idea: [Ability to edit standalone tables in ArcMap just as easily as feature classes](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/ability-to-edit-standalone-tables-in-arcmap-just/idc-p/1266729/highlight/true#M23727)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and to me it seems to be a software limitation.

I notice that the Help for [Copying and pasting records in a table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/copying-and-pasting-records-in-a-table.htm) alludes to this limitation when it says:

> This method of copying and pasting records is only valid for attribute
>   tables of layers. It will not work for tables that have no associated
>   features or tables in a database.

You could try to have this limitation lifted via [ArcGIS Ideas](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) where you could upvote [Ability to edit standalone tables in ArcMap just as easily as feature classes](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/1528).

You may also want to look for whether this functionality is already present in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will do. Strange, I don't see the equivalent to 'Copying and pasting records in a table' for ArcGIS Pro. That would be the only way I'd be able to check.